# Flexslider with manualControls and controlNav

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am trying to incorporate both manualControls and controlNav with a flexslider instance, but both features not working together, If I activate manualControls only manualControls wil work, Is there any fix or am I missing some thing, below is my code

```
 $('.home_slider').flexslider({
                animation: "slide",
                slideshow: false,
                directionNav: false,
                manualControls: ".slide_controll li",
                controlsContainer: ".home_banner",
                controlNav: true
});
```

If it is not possible, is there any other way to create another custom controls

Here is my fiddle:   [jsfiddle for my slider](http://jsfiddle.net/salih/jpyh4kLn/2)

Comment: Can you post your HTML code of the slider or give a jsfiddle to give a better help please?

Comment: @CarlosCalla - here is the fiddle -  http://jsfiddle.net/salih/jpyh4kLn/2/      If I comment out the manualControls: ".slide_controll li", line I will get usual black dot control navs

Answer (score 3):

There are different approaches you can solve this scenario. First of all, I tried playing around with the options given by the plugin. I experienced that if you use `manualControls` then the controls given by `controlNav` hide. That was what you experienced so a couple of ideas came up to my mind.

The first idea was to create a custom navigation controls and assign them the events that the default controls have. Thinking about this I concluded would be a little bit tedious because you have to assign the click event but also when the default control is clicked you gotta update the custom controls, then not only click but touch, keyup (because you can also control it with keyboard arrows) and it is doable but you gotta make sure you don't miss anything.

Second idea was using the properties `asNavFor` or `sync`. Sincerely, is the first time I see this plugin. I tried using `asNavFor` but didn't work I don't know why but I assume someway that have to work. I moved on to use `sync`. I thought I can leave the slider with the default controls and do another slider that is gonna be hidden but with custom controls and use the `sync` property to sync both sliders, so both controls will control the first slider because the second one is going to be hidden. I came up with a working sample in this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jpyh4kLn/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="flexslider" id="main-slider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="flexslider" id="nav-slider">
        <ul class="slides">
            <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <ul class="slide_controll">
        <li>Various Aria 1</li>
        <li>Various Aria 2</li>
        <li>Various Aria 3</li>
        <li>Various Aria 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Notice `#nav-slider` is the one that is hidden but is synced with the `#main-slider` so `#nav-slider`'s controls also control `#main-slider`, but you only see the first slider.

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $('#main-slider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        slideshow: false,
        directionNav: false,
        controlNav: true
    });

    $('#nav-slider').flexslider({
        directionNav: false,
        slideshow: false,
        sync: '#main-slider',
        manualControls: ".slide_controll li",
        controlsContainer: ".container"
    });
})
```

And on the CSS I added this styles to the `#nav-slider` to hide it:

```
#nav-slider {
    height: 0;
    margin: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    padding; 0
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
}
```

You can add more styles there or take some styles off, padding is 0 by default but I added that just in case. Notice that I didn't use `display: none;` as this would be ideal for the element no to take space from the DOM but when I used `display: none;` then it's controls (`#nav-slider`'s controls) wouldn't work. That's why I used 0 height, width, opacity, margin, padding, or everything that can take space, maybe border or any style that your slider can have.

This is a good workaround since you are using `sync` property from the plugin and I am making sure no event is missed from one control to another, they are working together as one.

Comment: Thanks for you  workaround, but a little issue is here, When I use manual Control, the ControlNav item also get assigned 'flex-active' for the right items, but if I use ControlNav I mean if I click through ControlNav the ManualControl Items not assigned the 'flex-active' class???

Comment: Hi, the class 'flex-active' is being assigned in both controls, the ones from the controlNav and the ones from the manualControls. The reason you don't see them changing is because you have to add the styles for them. Try adding this in your CSS file to see a visual difference: .slide_controll li.flex-active { color: red; }    . Sorry I couldn't use the code format but I am writting from my smartphone right now.

Comment: sorry, I think I misdirected you, what I was saying is, When I click on manual control(If i add your css), of course the current slide control will be in color red, the grey circles also will be changed to dark(ie, assigned active class), right. But it is not working vice versa,  ie, If i click throw the grey circles(controlNav), corresponding manualControls will not be assigned the active class. [eg, first click on the Second manual Cntrl(Various Area 2), you can see that will be assigned active class, also the above controlNav element also get assigned active class(ie becomes darker) ];